# How do I restore the high resolution in my external monitor with the MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I plugged in an extra high-resolution display — the likes of which we might have used in the 90s with a tube monitor but have been very difficult to come by lately.

When I plugged this display into the MacBook Pro, it registered many more pixels than the Retina display and I could position my code on the screen and see everything. The text was tiny.

I have no clue what the resolution was at that time, as it was selected automatically.

---

About 30 seconds later, both the new monitor and the MacBook Pro blacked out, and my nice and tiny text turned into giant text as the Mac rescaled the monitor to have identical or slightly fewer pixels than the main "Retina" display.

I have modified every setting in the display panel, I cannot go higher than 1600x900 on the external display.  However, when I plug this display into my Windows computer, I can go as high as 3200x1600 and display twice as much information with normal, tiny-sized text on the high-resolution monitor.

How do I restore this behavior on the Mac?

---

I "fixed" it with a reboot.  The key question is: How did that work? Why didn't I have access to the settings that would affect this with the live system?

How is that sausage getting made?  Do I have full visibility of the system when I am on it?

Comment: What make and model is the display?

Comment: You might want to look into https://www.madrau.com SwitchResX